# gitk label text - can it be displayed?

Tags: git, gitk

In git I have added a tag to my repository. In git it shows correctly as *'Release_1_0'* but in the gitk UI it shows as *'tag...'*

**Illustration of tag-labeling question**

[image]

**Question**

Can you get the tag to show in gitk as it's title? Specifically can we show the text *'Release_1_0'* instead of *'tag...'* in the yellow gitk tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me and I fixed the issue as follows:

1. Pull the border between the left pane and the middle pane, all the way to the right

[image]

2. Close gitk
3. Reopen gitk

[image]

Comment: Adi, you have added a rad bump of awesomeness to my morning with this fix. Thanks!!!! :)

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad I could help :-)